# How do I get a series of buttons to copy text from an input field into a series of input fields whose IDs match button IDs

Tags: jquery, button, input

I have this select list that loads a number of text input boxes with a button. The selected value determines the number of text input boxes and buttons that appear.

```
<p class="clrHexList" id="hexVals">Colors: Hex (#) values
    <select name="howManyClrs" id="numOfClrs">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
</p>
<br />
```

I also have another text input box that is loaded with a HEX value from a color picker.

```
<p><input type="text" id="origHex" /></p>
```

Here are all the text input boxes and button pairs.

```
<p class="clrHex" id="color1">1. &#35; <input class="hex" type="text" name="c1" id="clr1" /><button type="button" class="cpy" id="btn1">Copy from picker</button></p>
<p class="clrHex" id="color2">2. &#35; <input class="hex" type="text" name="c2" id="clr2" /><button type="button" class="cpy" id="btn2">Copy from picker</button></p>
<p class="clrHex" id="color3">3. &#35; <input class="hex" type="text" name="c3" id="clr3" /><button type="button" class="cpy" id="btn3">Copy from picker</button></p>
<p class="clrHex" id="color4">4. &#35; <input class="hex" type="text" name="c4" id="clr4" /><button type="button" class="cpy" id="btn4">Copy from picker</button></p>
<p class="clrHex" id="color5">1. &#35; <input class="hex" type="text" name="c5" id="clr5" /><button type="button" class="cpy" id="btn5">Copy from picker</button></p>
<p class="clrHex" id="color6">1. &#35; <input class="hex" type="text" name="c6" id="clr6" /><button type="button" class="cpy" id="btn6">Copy from picker</button></p>
<p class="clrHex" id="color7">1. &#35; <input class="hex" type="text" name="c7" id="clr7" /><button type="button" class="cpy" id="btn7">Copy from picker</button></p>
<p class="clrHex" id="color8">1. &#35; <input class="hex" type="text" name="c8" id="clr8" /><button type="button" class="cpy" id="btn8">Copy from picker</button></p>
```

I want to use jQuery for this. I want to be able to push the button to copy the text into its corresponding text input box. I have the following jQuery, but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

```
$('button.cpy').each(function() {
    var boxNum = $('#numOfClrs').val();
    $('#btn' + boxNum).on('click', function() {
        $('input#clr' + boxNum).val() = $('#origHex').val();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Here's how i'd skin this cat... brace yourself :P

> Note: And Unlike Other suggestions atm, this is scalable, you can have
>   as many input<->button pairs as you desire.

**First We create html DOM.**

```
<p class="clrHexList" id="hexVals">Colors: Hex (#) values
<select name="howManyClrs" id="numOfClrs">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
```

**Then**, we add the color chooser(just a text box for now, you can add it later) and a container div to hold up our input and button pairs

```
<p><input type="text" id="origHex" /></p>
<div id="conty"></div>
```

**Now** we add a sample model of our dom elements to be added

```
<p class="clrHex" id="color1" style="display:none">1. &#35; <input class="hex" type="text" name="c1" id="clr1" /><button type="button" class="cpy" id="btn1">Copy from picker</button></p>
```

Now's the time for <strike>Fireworks</strike> **JQuery**,

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#numOfClrs").change(function() {
        $("#conty").html("");
        var num = $(this).val();
        for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            $("#color1").clone().attr('id', 'id' + i).css("display", "block").appendTo("#conty");
            $('input', '#id' + i).attr({'id': 'c' + i, name: 'c' + i});
            $('button', '#id' + i).attr('id', 'btn' + i);
        }
        $(".cpy").click(function() {
            $(this).prev('input').val($("#origHex").val());
        });
    });
});
```

**And We are Done!!!**    [**JSbin!**](http://jsbin.com/okAxoFeF/1/)

Comment: This really is a lovely solution, and I appreciate the time you took to show me. I actually implemented labels instead so that users couldn't manually change the input values (they're going into a DB). I will save this for later, though!

Comment: Care to up-vote or select one of these as an answer??

Comment: What do you mean "unlike other suggestions", you just took my answer and messed it up by putting one event handler inside another event handler ?

Comment: Frankly speaking, I never had your answer in mind while answering, so I came up with all of this all by myself, and rest is coincidence... AND about the "other suggestions" part, I am talking about the scalability that my answer offers in terms of the input button pairs(lessening code redundancy)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input#clr' + boxNum).val() = $('#origHex').val();
```

should be

```
$('input#clr' + boxNum).val($('#origHex').val());
```

Also remove this:

```
$('button.cpy').each(function() {
```

jQuery does that for you when you use `$('#btn' + boxNum).on('click', function() ...`

### Final code:

```
var boxNum = $('#numOfClrs').val();
$('.cpy').on('click', function() {
    $('#clr' + boxNum).val($('#origHex').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.cpy', function() {
    $(this).prev().val($('#origHex').val());
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/76qj8/)